# Replace char with ASCII value inside number string

Tags: php, regex

Hi I have the following string consisting of letters and numbers **"00G990010020100038"** and I want to replace the letter for their ASCII value, in fact there can be only one letter inside the string, the position is what it changes.

I tried using preg_replace with no success, maybe I'm doing something wrong.

```
preg_replace("/[a-zA-Z]/", ord('$\1'), $mystring)
```

My code substitutes the letter for ASCII value of character '$' but I want 'G' (in this case) to be replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_replace("/[a-zA-Z]/e", "ord('\\0')", $mystring)
```

The /e modifier lets you execute PHP in the replacement.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `preg_replace_callback` instead. [It's more efficient than the `e` modifier.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php#73063)

```
preg_replace_callback(
    "/[a-zA-Z]/",
    create_function('$matches','return ord($matches[0]);'),
    $mystring
);
```